# Laravel Repositories

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

What are the advantages of Repositories in Laravel? It seems to be abstracting the Model layer from the business logic of the application. Although it really just seems to make the whole request life cycle just that much more complicated for little gain.

Can someone shed light on the advantage of Laravel repositories?

---

#### Edit

After now using repositories for some time I would add the following:

- Repositories enforce single responsibility
- Repositories should only return one collection of entities
- Although separate from dependancy injection the concepts are brothers
- Storage abstraction for the actual storage implementation (e.g. MySQL)
- Easier testing

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by Repositories? Are you talking Collections, the split of Laravel into multiple components (under the Illuminate name), something else?

Comment: here is a good explanation https://github.com/conarwelsh/nettuts-laravel4-and-backbone#repository

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Repositories, like in the provided tutorial, aren't necessary a Laravel concept. Rather, they're a form of IoC injection that is possible with Laravel. Any object that might similarly be injected doesn't mean it's a repository. See the video for a good example from Taylor Otwell, which happens to use a "repository" as well: http://vimeo.com/53029232.

In this example, the repository abstracts where the data came from that is passed to the controller. As long as the data passed  implements the specified interface, the controller can "blissfully" make use of the interface's defined methods without worry about where the data initially came from. This allows switching the initial source of the data without breaking your controller. You could pull the data from a file, a database, an outside API, a mock object, or just some arbitrary array. Basically, the controller doesn't need to gather the data represented by the repository. It can just receive and use.

Comment: Very well explained. That has cleared it up. So understanding your explanation... Its really effective means of unit testing and abstracting the data layer?

Comment: Yep! It's like the same principle you should shoot for with views, where they should have no idea where the heck their data came from, just know how to work with it to achieve the view's goal.

The short-term goals aren't obvious, but when it comes time to unit test, implement caching, use an in-memory cache database, the benefits will show themselves.

Answer (score 2):

Repositories help to keep your controller clean and make reusable code. Functions in repositories can be accessed in one or more controllers, repositories, etc.

Also, all your backend related logic (like fetching data from database or external calls) can be added in repositories to make the logical separation.

One of the main uses of repositories is to create different binding (using interfaces to define your functions and with the help of the app, bind different implementations of the function as per need). For example, two separate repositories (implementing the parent repository/interface) handling database and files for backend data.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other answers here, it's worth pointing out that repositories used when used in Laravel can add an extra level of expressiveness. Take for example the following:

```
$users = User::whereHas("role", function($q) {
    $q->where('name', 'moderator');
}, '<', 1)->get();
```

The code is difficult to read and awkward to look at. It can be encapsulated in a repository method, and demonstrate much clearer code intent:

```
$users = $userRepository->getUsersWhoAreNotModerators();
```

This is also achievable using eloquent 'query scopes' but I think using a repository is superior, as is adheres much better to the single responsibility principal, and is doable regardless of whether you are using Eloquent.

Answer (score 1):

The main reason you use repository pattern is to be able to easily change your data source. For example, in my experience the most common change is adding a caching layer, because the repository implements an interface all you need to do is build the new object implementing the same interface with the new methods handling cache and change the binding.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience the repository in Laravel benefits are these:

1. The most important thing by using repositories is that you can change your ORM any time and for any reason that you prefer. for example, you want to migrate from MySQL eloquent to some other SQLite ORM.
2. Helps you to keep your controllers clean and readable.
3. Helps you to reuse your methods in a repository for any other controllers.
4. You can add BaseRepository to your repositories list, which involves all base methods like `all()`, `get()`, `findOrFail()`, `firstOrFail()`, `paginate()`, `create()`, ... and use them in other repositories.
5. Using Interfaces for repositories and binding them that also can be used as services in Laravel.