# Laravel Model changing to API

Tags: php, design-patterns, laravel-4

I have a question in regards to design/refactoring an existing app. My existing app is in Laravel. We have models like User, which you would imagine be linked to the Users table in the database.
**Now I am planning to move this User table to an external database, which can be reached from my application with an API call.**
In all the Different parts of the application there are calls to the Current User Model like User::find(Id). This wont work anymore since now Users table is not there anymore in the database.

**1st Question:** how to accomplish the above by changing the model reference to call an API instead of a DB table. Is there any design pattern that can be leveraged so that I dont have to change all the User::find in all of the applications.

**2nd Question:** How would you handle places where the table is directly referenced by joins. Like table.x = User.x

Any help/guidance would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What it sounds like you need is a layer that sits over your models (perhaps something similar to the [Repository Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17367159/laravel-repositories)). This way you can abstract out your data access layer (currently Models) and make it easily swappable for another implementation (such as API requests). This is a bit more work in Laravel 4 than 5, and may possibly require significant refactoring.

As for your second question, your API will have to govern more advanced queries and have an endpoint/method for them.

Comment: Thank You very much